# Can the person accessing a web app macro link have access to my script or spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to know if it is safe to share the link to a table I created on the internet, the link is this:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz2Q42n872sFWL0Rkf-ntFFW7jb86YBIDhNRR6qy0OQLykK7YY/exec

I don't want people to be able to access my script and spreadsheet where it contains the data I share.

Comment: When I saw the HTML of your URL, I confirmed that the HTML table like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vce4jp5s/) and the deployment ID which is included in your URL. Although I could find the function names like `"JogosNaTv","EnviarTelegram","myFunction","doGet","getSheetData"`, I couldn't find your whole script and the Spreadsheet ID. Is this the answer for your question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike That is exactly what I would like to know, these names you found are the names of the functions I have in the script, but there is nothing important in showing this.  the important thing is that nothing leads to the script and the spreadsheet.  thank you very much my friend, you took my doubt completely!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer by adding the pattern which runs Javascript. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result I confirmed your URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz2Q42n872sFWL0Rkf-ntFFW7jb86YBIDhNRR6qy0OQLykK7YY/exec` is as follows.

- When I saw the HTML of your URL by downloading the HTML data (in this case, Javascript is not run.), I confirmed that the HTML table like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vce4jp5s/) and the deployment ID which is included in your URL.
- Although I could find the function names like `"JogosNaTv","EnviarTelegram","myFunction","doGet","getSheetData"`, I couldn't find your whole script and the Spreadsheet ID. Is this the answer for your question?
- When I saw the HTML of your URL while Javascript is running, I couldn't find the information about your script and the Spreadsheet ID, although I could find the function names like `"JogosNaTv","EnviarTelegram","myFunction","doGet","getSheetData"`.